# How to define when a class is empty

Tags: python, class

I wrote my own vector class:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class V:
    """Defines a 2D vector"""
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self,other):
        newx = self.x + other.x
        newy = self.y + other.y
        return V(newx,newy)
    def __sub__(self,other):
        newx = self.x - other.x
        newy = self.y - other.y
        return V(newx,newy)
    def __str__(self):
        return "V({x},{y})".format(x=self.x,y=self.y)
```

I want to define that V(0,0) is an empty vector, such that this would work: (The first case should return "Vector is empty")

```
v = V(0,0)
u = V(1,2)

if u:
    print (u)
else:
    print("Vector is empty")

if v:
    print(v)
else:
    print("Vector is empty")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define [**`__bool__`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), like this:

```
class V:
    """Defines a 2D vector"""
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.x != 0 or self.y != 0

    # Python 2 compatibility
    __nonzero__ = __bool__
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't do anything in Python 2, which the OP's `print` syntax suggests they're using. The correct method is `__nonzero__`

Comment: @Wooble Thanks, added `__nonzero__` to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can implement the special method [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

```
def __bool__ (self):
    return self.x != 0 or self.y != 0
```

Note that in Python 2, the special method is named [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

<s>Alternatively, because you have a vector, it might make even more sense to implement [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) and provide the actual vector length instead. If `__bool__` is not defined, Python will automatically try to use the `__len__` method to get the length and evaluate if it’s not zero.</s>

Comment: When I try to evaluate the length of the vector I get: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: That's because ``__len__`` has to return an integer. The real vector length isn't always an integer, so i'd rather just implement ``__bool__``.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Good point about the integer return value! Didn’t think of that.

Comment: About the `__len__` method, would that be more intended for getting the size of something that stores a number of elements (like characters in a `str` or items in a `list`)?

Comment: the way you would have python tell you the 'vector length' is with `abs()`, for which the special method name is `__abs__()`

Comment: @SimonT Yeah, or anything that is composed of other things where the count of those other things matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just concerned about the output. Just extend the **`__str__`** method.

```
def __str__( self ):
    if self.x and self.y :
        return "V({x},{y})".format( x = self.x, y = self.y )
    else:
        return "Vector is empty"



v = V( 0, 0 )
u = V( 1, 2 )
print v
print u
```

Output will be:

Vector is empty

V(1,2)